# Transform std:vector<reference_wrapper<Base>> to std:vector<reference_wrapper<Derived>> Runtime error time: 0 memory: 3412 signal:6

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, reference-wrapper

I am trying to convert vector of references to Base objects to vector of references to Derived objects. Everything is compiling fine, but i got this error: Runtime error time: 0 memory: 3412 signal:6

This is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>

using namespace std;

struct B {
    B(int i) { b = i; }
    virtual ~B() {}
    int b;
};

struct D: public B {
    D(int i): B(i) {}
};

typedef vector<reference_wrapper<B>> refB;
typedef vector<reference_wrapper<D>> refD;

void dynamicCast(refB &b, refD &d)
{
    for(const auto& bb: b)
    {
        d.push_back(dynamic_cast<D&> (bb.get()));
    }
}

int main() {
    vector<B*> numbers;
    refB refNumbers;
    refD dNumbers;

    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        numbers.push_back(new B(2*i));
        refNumbers.push_back(*numbers[i]);
    }

    dynamicCast(refNumbers, dNumbers);

    return 0;
}
```

What is wrong with dynamicCast() function?

EDIT:
@John Zwinck answer helped, but when i try to do this in my code i got compilation error:

> cannot dynamic_cast '(&
>   obj)->std::reference_wrapper<_Tp>::get()' (of type 'class
>   MEPObject') to type 'class MEPGene&' (target is not pointer or
>   reference to complete type)
>            genes.push_back(dynamic_cast (obj.get()));

```
class MEPObject;
class MEPGene;
typedef std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<MEPObject>> MEPObjects;
typedef std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<MEPGene>> MEPGenes;

void dynamicCast(MEPObjects &objects, MEPGenes &genes)
{
    for(const auto &obj: objects)
    {
        genes.push_back(dynamic_cast<MEPGene&> (obj.get()));
    }
}
                                                      ^
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing is wrong with `dynamicCast()`.  The problem is here:

```
    numbers.push_back(new B(2*i));
```

You only ever construct instances of `B` which is the base class.  You can't possibly cast them to `D` which is the derived class.

Perhaps you meant to construct derived instances and store them in your vector of references to base.

Comment: How can I replace loop with std::transform function? I tried:
`transform(b.begin(), b.end(), d.begin(), [](reference_wrapper<B> &bb) { return dynamic_cast<D&> (bb.get()); });`